# How to calculate monthly normals?

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
            CODE    TMAX  TMIN   PP
DATE                              
1991-01-01  000130  32.6  23.4  0.0
1991-01-02  000130  31.2  22.4  0.0
1991-01-03  000130  32.0   NaN  0.0
1991-01-04  000130  32.2  23.0  0.0
1991-01-05  000130  30.5  22.0  0.0
           ...   ...   ...  ...
2020-12-27  158328   NaN   NaN  NaN
2020-12-28  158328   NaN   NaN  NaN
2020-12-29  158328   NaN   NaN  NaN
2020-12-30  158328   NaN   NaN  NaN
2020-12-31  158328   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

I have data of 30 years (1991-2020) for each CODE, and i want to calculate monthly normals of TMAX, TMIN and PP. So for TMAX and TMIN i should calculate the average for every month, so if January have 31 days i should get the mean of those 31 values and get a value for January 1991, January 1992, etc. So i will have 30 Januarys (January 1991, January 1992, ... ,January 2020), 30 Februarys, etc. After this i should calculate the average of every group of months (Januarys with Januarys, Februarys with Februarys, etc). So i will have 12 values (one value for every month). Example:
(January1991 + January1992 + ..... + January 2020) /30
(February1991 + February1992 + ..... + February 2020) /30
.... same for every group of months.

So i'm using this code but i don't know if it's ok.

```
from datetime import date
normalstemp=df[['CODE','TMAX','TMIN']].groupby([df.CODE, df.index.month]).mean().round(1)
```

For PP (precipitation) i should sum the values of every PP value of the month, so if January have 31 days i should sum all of their values and get a value for January 1991, January 1992, etc. So i will have 30 Januarys (January 1991, January 1992, ... ,January 2020) , 30 Februarys (February 1991, February 1992, ... ,February 2020), etc. After this i should calculate the average of every group of months (Januarys with Januarys, Februarys with Februarys, etc). So i will have 12 values (one value for every month, the same as TMAX and TMIN).

Example:
(January1991 + January1992 + ..... + January 2020) /30
(February1991 + February1992 + ..... + February 2020) /30
.... same for every group of months.

So im using this code but i know this code isn't correct because i'm not getting the mean of the januarys, februarys, etc.

```
normalspp=df[['CODE','PP']].groupby([df.CODE, df.index.month]).sum().round(1)
```

I only have basic knowledge of python so i will appreciate if you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to calculate average of each month within each year?

Comment: I will be more specific. First i want to calculate the average of each month. So i want the mean of the values of January 1991, January 1992....... , February 1991, February 1992,.... December 1991, December 1992, ... December 2020. Then i want the average of each group of months like this: (January 1991 + January 1992 + .... January 2020)/30, (February 1991 + February 1992 + .... February 2020)/30, etc etc. Those values must be 12 values by code.

Comment: You have 30 years between 1991 and 2020. So you want averages of 360 months and then you want 12 averages - one for each month (the average is of the same month for 30 years). Is that correct?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the information from your comments section. I will modify my code and share the results shortly

Comment: Yeah it is correct. Thanks. I updated my question.

Comment: See if the updated version addresses the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ver 2: Average by Year-Month and by Month

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1991', end='12/31/2020',freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':x.tolist()*2,
                   'Code':['000130']*10958 + ['158328']*10958,
                   'TMAX': np.random.randint(6,10, size=21916),
                   'TMIN': np.random.randint(1,5, size=21916)
                  })

# Create a Month column to get Average by Month for all years

df['Month'] = df.Date.dt.month

# Create a Year-Month column to get Average of each Month within the Year

df['Year_Mon'] = df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

# Print the Average of each Month within each Year for each code

print (df.groupby(['Code','Year_Mon'])['TMAX'].mean())
print (df.groupby(['Code','Year_Mon'])['TMIN'].mean())

# Print the Average of each Month irrespective of the year (for each code)

print (df.groupby(['Code','Month'])['TMAX'].mean())
print (df.groupby(['Code','Month'])['TMAX'].mean())
```

If you want to give a name for the TMAX Average value, you can add the reset_index and rename column. Here's code to do that.

```
print (df.groupby(['Code','Year_Mon'])['TMAX'].mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'TMAX':'TMAX_Avg'}))
```

The output of this will be:

Average of TMAX for each Year-Month for each Code

```
Code    Year_Mon
000130  1991-01     7.225806
        1991-02     7.678571
        1991-03     7.354839
        1991-04     7.500000
        1991-05     7.516129
                      ...   
158328  2020-08     7.387097
        2020-09     7.300000
        2020-10     7.516129
        2020-11     7.500000
        2020-12     7.451613
Name: TMAX, Length: 720, dtype: float64
```

Average of TMIN for each Year-Month for each Code

```
Code    Year_Mon
000130  1991-01     2.419355
        1991-02     2.571429
        1991-03     2.193548
        1991-04     2.366667
        1991-05     2.451613
                      ...   
158328  2020-08     2.451613
        2020-09     2.566667
        2020-10     2.612903
        2020-11     2.666667
        2020-12     2.580645
Name: TMIN, Length: 720, dtype: float64
```

Average of TMAX for each Month for each Code (all years combined)

```
Code    Month
000130  1        7.540860
        2        7.536557
        3        7.482796
        4        7.486667
        5        7.444086
        6        7.570000
        7        7.507527
        8        7.529032
        9        7.501111
        10       7.401075
        11       7.482222
        12       7.517204
158328  1        7.532258
        2        7.563679
        3        7.490323
        4        7.555556
        5        7.500000
        6        7.497778
        7        7.545161
        8        7.483871
        9        7.526667
        10       7.529032
        11       7.547778
        12       7.524731
Name: TMAX, dtype: float64
```

Average of TMIN for each Month for each Code (all years combined)

```
Code    Month
000130  1        7.540860
        2        7.536557
        3        7.482796
        4        7.486667
        5        7.444086
        6        7.570000
        7        7.507527
        8        7.529032
        9        7.501111
        10       7.401075
        11       7.482222
        12       7.517204
158328  1        7.532258
        2        7.563679
        3        7.490323
        4        7.555556
        5        7.500000
        6        7.497778
        7        7.545161
        8        7.483871
        9        7.526667
        10       7.529032
        11       7.547778
        12       7.524731
Name: TMAX, dtype: float64
```

## Ver 1: Average by Year and Month for each Code

Here is one way to do this.

You can create two columns - Year and Month. Then get the average of TMAX, TMIN, and PP for each month within the year by doing a `groupby ('Code','Year_Mon')`

See code for more details.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a range of dates from 1/1/2018 thru 12/31/2020 for each day

x = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='12/31/2020',freq='D')

# create a dataframe with the date ranges x 2 for two codes
# TMIN is a random value from 1 thru 5  - you can put your actual data here
# TMAX is a random value from 6 thru 10 - you can put your actual data here

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':x.tolist()*2,
                   'Code':['000130']*1096 + ['158328']*1096,
                   'TMAX': np.random.randint(6,10, size=2192),
                   'TMIN': np.random.randint(1,5, size=2192)
                  })

# Create a Year-Month column using df.Date.dt.strftime

df['Year_Mon'] = df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

# Calculate the Average of TMAX and TMIN using groupby Code and Year_Mon

df['TMAX_Avg'] = df.groupby(['Code','Year_Mon'])['TMAX'].transform('mean')
df['TMIN_Avg'] = df.groupby(['Code','Year_Mon'])['TMIN'].transform('mean')
```

The output of this will be:

```
         Date    Code  TMAX  TMIN Year_Mon  TMAX_Avg  TMIN_Avg
0  2018-01-01  000130     8     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
1  2018-01-02  000130     7     4  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
2  2018-01-03  000130     9     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
3  2018-01-04  000130     6     1  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
4  2018-01-05  000130     9     4  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
5  2018-01-06  000130     6     1  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
6  2018-01-07  000130     9     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
7  2018-01-08  000130     9     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
8  2018-01-09  000130     7     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
9  2018-01-10  000130     8     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
10 2018-01-11  000130     8     3  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
11 2018-01-12  000130     7     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
12 2018-01-13  000130     7     1  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
13 2018-01-14  000130     8     1  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
14 2018-01-15  000130     7     3  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
15 2018-01-16  000130     6     1  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
16 2018-01-17  000130     6     3  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
17 2018-01-18  000130     9     3  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
18 2018-01-19  000130     7     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
19 2018-01-20  000130     8     1  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
20 2018-01-21  000130     9     4  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
21 2018-01-22  000130     6     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
22 2018-01-23  000130     9     4  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
23 2018-01-24  000130     6     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
24 2018-01-25  000130     8     3  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
25 2018-01-26  000130     6     2  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
26 2018-01-27  000130     8     1  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
27 2018-01-28  000130     8     3  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
28 2018-01-29  000130     6     1  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
29 2018-01-30  000130     6     1  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
30 2018-01-31  000130     8     1  2018-01  7.451613  2.129032
31 2018-02-01  000130     7     1  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
32 2018-02-02  000130     6     2  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
33 2018-02-03  000130     6     4  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
34 2018-02-04  000130     8     3  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
35 2018-02-05  000130     8     2  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
36 2018-02-06  000130     6     3  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
37 2018-02-07  000130     6     3  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
38 2018-02-08  000130     7     1  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
39 2018-02-09  000130     9     4  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
40 2018-02-10  000130     8     2  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
41 2018-02-11  000130     7     4  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
42 2018-02-12  000130     8     1  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
43 2018-02-13  000130     6     4  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
44 2018-02-14  000130     6     1  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
45 2018-02-15  000130     6     4  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
46 2018-02-16  000130     8     2  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
47 2018-02-17  000130     7     3  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
48 2018-02-18  000130     9     3  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
49 2018-02-19  000130     8     2  2018-02  7.250000  2.428571
```

If you want only the Code, Year-Month, and TMIN and TMAX values, you can do:

TMAX average for each month within the year:

```
print (df.groupby(['Code','Year_Mon'])['TMAX'].mean())
```

Output will be:

```
Code    Year_Mon
000130  2018-01     7.451613
        2018-02     7.250000
        2018-03     7.774194
        2018-04     7.366667
        2018-05     7.451613
                      ...   
158328  2020-08     7.935484
        2020-09     7.666667
        2020-10     7.548387
        2020-11     7.333333
        2020-12     7.580645
```

TMIN average for each month within the year:

```
print (df.groupby(['Code','Year_Mon'])['TMIN'].mean())
```

Output will be:

```
Code    Year_Mon
000130  2018-01     2.129032
        2018-02     2.428571
        2018-03     2.451613
        2018-04     2.500000
        2018-05     2.677419
                      ...   
158328  2020-08     2.709677
        2020-09     2.166667
        2020-10     2.161290
        2020-11     2.366667
        2020-12     2.548387
```